# Local aggregation for data stream in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to find a good way to combine Flink keyed WindowedStream locally for Flink application. The idea is to similar to a combiner in MapReduce: to combine partial results in each partition (or mapper) before the data (which is still a keyed WindowedStream) is sent to a global aggregator (or reducer). The closest function I found is: [aggregate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5582) but I was't be able to find a good example for the usage on WindowedStream.

It looks like aggregate doesn't allow a WindowedStream output. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: There's an open "FLIP" to address this need: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-44%3A+Support+Local+Aggregation+in+Flink

Answer (score 0):

There have been some initiatives to provide pre-aggregation in Flink. You have to implement your own operator. In the case of stream environment you have to extend the class AbstractStreamOperator.
KurtYoung implemented a [BundleOperator](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/blink/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/bundle/BundleOperator.java). You can also use the Table API on top of the stream API. The Table API is already providing a [local aggregation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tuning/streaming_aggregation_optimization.html#local-global-aggregation). I also have one example of the [pre-aggregate operator](https://felipeogutierrez.blogspot.com/2019/04/implementing-my-own-stream-operator-in.html) that I implemented myself. Usually, the drawback of all those solutions is that you have to set the number of items to pre-aggregate or the timeout to pre-aggregate. If you don't have it you can run out of memory, or you never shuffle items (if the threshold number of items is not achieved). In other words, they are rule-based. What I would like to have is something that is cost-based, more dynamic. I would like to have something that adjusts those parameters in run-time.

I hope these links can help you. And, if you have ideas for the cost-based solution, please come to talk with me =).